# MySQL query using minimum of rows as columns and averaging

Tags: mysql

I have a too complicated SQL problem (MySQL) for me and I need help.

I have a table with temperature readings. These readings are from a number of sensors placed at various locations. Each reading ocurred at a timestamp. Readings are made every ten minutes and because the reading happened sequentially between sensors there might be a second between individual sensor readings.

Two sensors read the outside temperature, which means that every ten minutes there are two readings (at Location=5 and Location=6) that reflect the outside temperature. These sensors are put on the north side and the south side of the building meaning that the lowest of the two readings are likely the most accurate, since the one with the highest can  currently be exposed  by sunlight.

So a sample of the table will look like this

```
SELECT * FROM Temperatures 
WHERE timestamp > "2016-07-01 15:00" 
AND timestamp < "2016-07-01 15:40"
AND (Location=5 OR Location=6) 
AND Site=3 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC

(`ReadingID`, `Timestamp`, `Site`, `Location`, `Temperature`)
(3921775, '2016-07-01 15:00:01', 3, 5, 18),
(3921776, '2016-07-01 15:00:02', 3, 6, 17.5),
(3921781, '2016-07-01 15:10:01', 3, 5, 18.6),
(3921782, '2016-07-01 15:10:03', 3, 6, 17.9),
(3921787, '2016-07-01 15:20:01', 3, 5, 18.4),
(3921788, '2016-07-01 15:20:01', 3, 6, 22.7),
(3921793, '2016-07-01 15:30:01', 3, 5, 19.4),
(3921794, '2016-07-01 15:30:02', 3, 6, 29.2);
```

As you can see the timestamp might differ with a second between location=5 and location=6 even if they have a strong time correlation.
At 15:00 and 15:10 location 6 is has the lowest temperature and 15:20 and 15:30 location 5 has the lowest temperature. The reading ID is irrelevant here.

What I want is the following:
1) Display the minimum of location 5 and location 6 for each 10 minute interval. How would this query look for a single day for example?
(Let's consider "2016-07-01 00:00" to "2016-07-01 23:50".

Ie. The following

```
(`Timestamp (as 10 minute interval)`, `Location`, `Min of location 5 and 6`)
'2016-07-01 00:00', <some data>
...
'2016-07-01 15:00', 6, 17.5
'2016-07-01 15:10', 6, 17.9
'2016-07-01 15:20', 5, 18.4
'2016-07-01 15:30', 5, 19.4
...
'2016-07-02 23:50', <some data>
```

2) What would the average outside temperature be for a single day in an interval of a month. That is the average temperature of "2016-07-01 00:00" to "2016-07-01 23:50", based on the minumum temperature of location 5 and location 6 for each 10 minut reading. How would you write that query?

In this latter case let's either assume that all the data is in place, ie. that there are really 144 readings a day (this is mostly the case) or let's assume that if a reading is missed it doesn't really affect the average som much.

Eg. the following result is wanted:

```
(`Date`, `Average based on min of location 5 and 6 for each 10 minute intervl`)
'2017-07-01', 12.0
'2017-07-02', 13.1
'2017-07-03', 12.9
etc.
'2017-07-31', 17.7
```

Best regards
Pål

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you can generate a series of date-hour-minute:

```
(select date_format(TimeStamp1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as TimeStamp, 
       min(Temperature) as Temperature 
 from Temperatures
 group by date_format(TimeStamp1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) tserie
```

and the return the location where timestamp and temperature matches.

```
select tserie.TimeStamp, Location, tserie.Temperature
from Temperatures
     inner join (select date_format(TimeStamp1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as TimeStamp, 
                        min(Temperature) as Temperature 
                 from Temperatures
                 group by date_format(TimeStamp1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) tserie
where date_format(TimeStamp1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = TimeStamp and tserie.Temperature = Temperatures.Temperature
;
```

This is the result:

```
+------------------+----------+-------------+
|     TimeStamp    | Location | Temperature |
+------------------+----------+-------------+
| 2016-07-01 15:00 |     6    |    17,50    |
| 2016-07-01 15:10 |     6    |    17,90    |
| 2016-07-01 15:20 |     5    |    18,40    |
| 2016-07-01 15:30 |     5    |    19,40    |
+------------------+----------+-------------+
```

For the 2nd part, using the same time series between two dates, calculate the average temperature:

```
select date_format(Tstamp2, '%Y-%m-%d') as Day, sum(Temperature) / count(*) as Avg
from  (select date_format(TimeStamp1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as Tstamp2, 
              min(Temperature) as Temperature 
       from Temperatures
       where TimeStamp1 >= '2016-07-01' and TimeStamp1 < '2016-08-01'
       group by date_format(TimeStamp1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) tserie
group by date_format(Tstamp2, '%Y-%m-%d')
;
```

The result:

```
+------------+-----------+
|     Day    |    Avg    |
+------------+-----------+
| 2016-07-01 | 18,300000 |
+------------+-----------+
| 2016-07-02 | 18,300000 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/BXJW4041

Comment: Thank you very much. I get a litte confused as you are not using the same table and column names as I really do. The table is called 'Temperatures' (and not sensors) and the timestamp column is called 'Timestamp' (and not Tstamp, which might be an unlucky choice). When I try to exchange for my names it doesn't work. And I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Would you mind altering your query so that it would work with my names?

Comment: Ok, I've set a new rextester, I've changed table name to Temperatures and Tstamp field to TimeStamp1 (I don't like to use reserved words for fieldnames). Try it here: http://rextester.com/BXJW4041

Comment: And that is probably wise to not use reserved names. I don't like it either and really don't know why it ended up that way, less that it works...However, this query seem also to be too heavy for the server, there is no response in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this query to get the min of each 10 Minutes

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(t1.Timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS `Timestamp`
    , IF( LEAST(t1.`Temperature`, t2.`Temperature`) = t1.`Temperature`, 
        IF(t1.`Temperature` = t2.`Temperature` , '5/6', 5 ), 6) AS Location
    , LEAST(t1.`Temperature`, t2.`Temperature`) AS Temperature
FROM Temperatures t1
LEFT JOIN Temperatures t2
ON
    t2.Location = 6 
AND
    t2.`TIMESTAMP` 
    BETWEEN 
        t1.`TIMESTAMP` - INTERVAL 5 SECOND
    AND 
        t1.`TIMESTAMP` + INTERVAL 5 SECOND
WHERE t1.Location = 5;
```

**sample**

It will shows you also if both sensors have the same temp.

```
mysql> select * from Temperatures;
+-----------+---------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| ReadingID | Timestamp           | Site | Location | Temperature |
+-----------+---------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|   3921775 | 2016-07-01 15:00:01 |    3 |        5 |      18.000 |
|   3921776 | 2016-07-01 15:00:02 |    3 |        6 |      17.500 |
|   3921781 | 2016-07-01 15:10:01 |    3 |        5 |      18.600 |
|   3921782 | 2016-07-01 15:10:03 |    3 |        6 |      17.900 |
|   3921787 | 2016-07-01 15:20:01 |    3 |        5 |      18.400 |
|   3921788 | 2016-07-01 15:20:01 |    3 |        6 |      22.700 |
|   3921793 | 2016-07-01 15:30:01 |    3 |        5 |      19.400 |
|   3921794 | 2016-07-01 15:30:02 |    3 |        6 |      29.200 |
|   3921795 | 2016-07-01 15:40:02 |    3 |        5 |      27.120 |
|   3921796 | 2016-07-01 15:40:04 |    3 |        6 |      27.120 |
+-----------+---------------------+------+----------+-------------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     DATE_FORMAT(t1.Timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS `Timestamp`
    ->     , IF( LEAST(t1.`Temperature`, t2.`Temperature`) = t1.`Temperature`,
    ->         IF(t1.`Temperature` = t2.`Temperature` , '5/6', 5 ), 6) AS Location
    ->     , LEAST(t1.`Temperature`, t2.`Temperature`) AS Temperature
    -> FROM Temperatures t1
    -> LEFT JOIN Temperatures t2
    -> ON
    ->     t2.Location = 6
    -> AND
    ->     t2.`TIMESTAMP`
    ->     BETWEEN
    ->         t1.`TIMESTAMP` - INTERVAL 5 SECOND
    ->     AND
    ->         t1.`TIMESTAMP` + INTERVAL 5 SECOND
    ->
    -> WHERE t1.Location = 5;
+------------------+----------+-------------+
| Timestamp        | Location | Temperature |
+------------------+----------+-------------+
| 2016-07-01 15:00 | 6        |      17.500 |
| 2016-07-01 15:10 | 6        |      17.900 |
| 2016-07-01 15:20 | 5        |      18.400 |
| 2016-07-01 15:30 | 5        |      19.400 |
| 2016-07-01 15:40 | 5/6      |      27.120 |
+------------------+----------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: This query gets to heavy on the server with all the data in the table. I think it needs to be restricted in time and site (Timestamp >= "2016-07-01 AND Timestamp <= "2016-07-31"  AND Site=3). I can't solve how to put that restriction in the query, could you please help?